# Client side geocoding with Javascript on Rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps-api-3, heroku

I am trying to client side geocode due to this issue I am having (over query limit on Heroku): https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/issues/222.

The lat/long display in my url however I cannot get my search results to display.

I think the issue is in the index.html.erb around line 10: <%  if params[:search].present? %>

B/c in my browser when I execute a search query, the debug params displays the params and it by-passes the 'if' statement and executes the 'else' instead, inferring that there are no search params present or that I'm not properly stating the 'if' statement.

Example search:

**URL:**`http://localhost:3000/places?utf8=✓&q=hoover%2C+alabama&c=%2833.4053867%2C+-86.81137810000001%29`

**Debug params:**
Hello
--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
utf8: ✓
q: hoover, alabama
c: (33.4053867, -86.81137810000001)
action: index
controller: places

Thoughts on why my search results are not displaying? Please see my comment below this post for a link to my relevant code.

Comment: This is my relevant code: https://gist.github.com/farooqyousuf/5224089

Comment: I tried to use this solution as provided per one of the comments in the github thread I posted in my question: https://gist.github.com/kurioscreative/3398483#file-search-html-haml

Answer (score 0):

hmm, i think ur form_tag method should be post instead of get?